# Calculating probability that the two person meet each other?

Tags: probability

Persons $X$, $Y$ have an appointment at a certain time.

Person $X$ delays up to an hour and a half to arrive at the meeting place, and person $Y$ has a delay of up to two hours to arrive at the meeting place.

Person $X$ half-hour individual meeting place and person $Y$ 0.75 hour meeting place will have to wait.

What is the probability that the two people meet each other?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the arrival times of $X$ and $Y$ are independent and equidistributed in the given intervals, $X$ is willing to wait at most $30$min and $Y$ is willing to wait at most $45$min, the wanted probability is given by the ratio between the area of the shaded region and the area of the enclosing rectangle:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

It follows that the wanted probability is
$$ \frac{1}{48}\left(48-\frac{9}{2}-\frac{64}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{23}{96}}\approx 23.96\%. $$